# how to append long html codes?

Tags: php, jquery

The following code can add div elements to the body. But sometimes the HTML is very long. If it is very long like 300 lines html codes, writing it like this is pratty hard:

```
$("body").append($("<div id='dzndiv'><div style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:100%;height:800px;'><img src='img/transparent.png' width='100%' height='100%'/></div>");
```

I think it should be like this:

```
$("body").append($.load("longstuff.html");
```

How can I do this? But important thing html codes can have space between tags.

Comment: I doubt that it should be done with another request to server. Why can't you include this content into HTML, and just hide it before it's needed?

Comment: result.html call myajax.php. this append method used in a php files: myajax.php...myajax.php gives a value into div tag and I have to show this div element in result.html...thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$.get('longstuff.html', function(data) {
    $('body').append(data);
}, 'html');
```

However, if you always/often need that HTML and it is static a pretty common way to store it without loading it via AJAX is using script tags:

```
<script type="text/html" id="long-stuff">
    <!-- simply put your HTML here -->
</script>
```

You can then access it via `$('#long-stuff').html()`

Depending on what you want to do another option would be simply putting the HTML at the place where it belongs and hide it using `style="display: none;"` and then `.show()` it later.

Comment: you can write this as use php;    $("body").append($("<?include('longstuff.html');?>"));    but yours and mine the html codes must be no space! I want to break space in my html codes!

Comment: That PHP solution is truly ugly. You'd need to escape stuff etc. Besides that, you did not ask for a PHP solution.

Comment: ok you can forget php. I try to explain html codes must have space in both of way!

Answer (score 0):

$.get('longstuff.html', function(data) {data=data.replace(/> 
this code can delete all space in html codes and html codes are appended into existing body tag. thanks for all asnwers.